# Error in tidygraph `as_tbl_graph` - mutliple logicals compared to single

Tags: r, tidygraph

I encountered an issue in the tidygraph package.

Here is an example code:

```r
library(tidygraph)
adj <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                 dim = c(15L, 15L), 
                 dimnames = list(paste0("v",1:15), 
                                 paste0("v",1:15)))

adj

tidygraph::as_tbl_graph(adj)
```

The error that I get is:

```r
Error in (is.null(rownames(x)) && is.null(colnames(x))) || colnames(x) ==  : 
  'length = 15' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

The error comes from the sub-function `guess_matrix_type` and there from the expression `colnames(x) == rownames(x)` which does not result in a single logical statement but multiple (that are then compared to a single one) here:

[image]

This used to work before (I think at least...). Any ideas on a workaround?

Comment: “This used to work before” — actually it *never* worked, but it used to be a *silent* error, which was recently made into an explicit (and noisy) error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your error, but the obvious workaround is to use `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` from `igraph`

```r
igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj) |>
  as_tbl_graph()
# A tbl_graph: 15 nodes and 22 edges
#
# A directed acyclic multigraph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 15 x 1 (active)
  name 
  <chr>
1 v1   
2 v2   
3 v3   
4 v4   
5 v5   
6 v6   
# ... with 9 more rows
#
# Edge Data: 22 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     3
2     2     6
3     3     4
# ... with 19 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it. In my case I needed the 'weighted = TRUE' option in the first command as well for a later use.

Comment: Also there is a fix for this here: 
https://github.com/thomasp85/tidygraph/pull/175